# What is uuid of IVssBackupComponentsEx4?

Tags: c++, com, volume-shadow-service

What is `UUID` of `IVssBackupComponentsEx4`?

I've looked all through MSDN site and did not find anything, also this documentation is not so good about VSS related components.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search the Windows SDK `include` directory for these kind of COM interface names.  You'll need at least version 8.0 since this is an interface that was added in Windows Server 2012.

From the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\vsbackup.h file in my machine:

```
const IID IID_IVssBackupComponentsEx4       = // f434c2fd-b553-4961-a9f9-a8e90b673e53
                    {
                    0xf434c2fd,
                    0xb553,
                    0x4961,
                    { 0xa9, 0xf9, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0x0b, 0x67, 0x3e, 0x53 }
                    };
```

With the additional note that you shouldn't hard-code these IIDs but use the `__uuidof` keyword in your code.  And that tagging the question with [visual-sourcesafe] is rather odd, this is a Volume Shadow Copy interface.